# How do I set a 10 char string to binary zero in c?

Tags: c

I have an IBM XL c program that calls an asm subroutine passing a struct. 
The asm program is called by COBOL and pl/1 programs also.
The asm program updates a file with contents of the passed structure but will ignore fields that contain binary zeros. How do I set (for example) a 10 char string field in the c program to contain x'00' in all 10 bytes (not just byte position 1)?

Yes dumb question I know.

Comment: Zero is zero, no matter how you turn it.

Comment: It would help if you would show us some code.

Comment: Depends if it is character zero (x'F0')  or binary zero (x'00') I want to fill the character string with binary zeroes. hence my struggle.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I set (for example) a 10 char string field in the c program to
>   contain x'00' in all 10 bytes (not just byte position 1)?

```
char a[10];
memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
```

I hope this is what you want.There are other simple ways

```
char a[10] = "";
char a[10] = {0};
```

Comment: I thought that put character zero (hex 'F0'  in as opposed to binary zero hex '00'.  This is EBCDIC as it is mainframe..

Comment: To change the memset from assigning binary zero to EBCDIC (or ascii) character zero you would do this: `memset(a,'0',sizeof(a));` (note the quote marks).  In other words: yes, Gopi's memset really does binary zero.